# ReactJS - Access to other component's state

Tags: reactjs

I know this is not possible straight, because states are private and other components can not get them. There must be some way to pass this.

Question is: How can I get access to another component state or function in another component?

I have 3 components: `SceondTimerList`, `SecondTimerNumber` and `SecondTimer` itself.

In `SecondTimer` I have state:

```
class SecondTimer extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      running: false, 
      currentTimeMs: 0,
      currentTimeSec: 0,
      currentTimeMin: 0,
    };
  }
```

And in `SecondTimerList` I have button and functions for clicking:

```
  tuplahomma = () => {
    this.saveTime();
    this.reset(); // Clearing name input field
  }

<Button className={"save-reset-nappi"} variant="success" size="lg" onClick={this.tuplahomma}>SAVE TIME</Button>
```

If the states would be in the same component I would do it like this, but it's not so..:

```
  resetCounter = () => {
    this.setState({
      currentTimeMs: 0,
      currentTimeSec: 0,
      currentTimeMin: 0,
    });
  };
```

[image: Laptimer app]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seem you have some problems in structuring your components. It's better to provide some simple codepen sample for example.

It's better to store sate data in root wrapper components where you can contain other components and path props and methods inside, example:

```
class TimerWrapper extends React.Component {
    state = {
      running: false,
      currentTimeMs: 0,
      currentTimeSec: 0,
      currentTimeMin: 0,
    }

    start = () => {}

    reset = () => {
      this.setState(); // reset data here
    }

    save = () => {}

    resetHistory = () => {}

    render() {

      return ( 
       <>
        <TopBarButtons start={this.start} reset={this.reset}/> 
        <Input { ...someProps}/> 
        <SaveTimeButton save={this.save}/> 
        <ResetTimeButton reset={this.reset}/> 
        <HistoryBlock { ...historyData}/> 
      < />
      )
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried this but not working like I as hoping. Maybe best way to do my case is trigger function in another component. I have this current time state in main component and there is also the function for setting value 0 to states.

In another component there is one button, `SAVE TIME` and clicking that I want trigger timereseting function in main component. Any tips?

Comment: What excatly not working? mb you have codepen jsfiddle or other example?

Comment: It saying there is double render and does not accept that. Throwing error. Can I send you message somehow? This commentbox is so small. I would like to tell you the problem .

Comment: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225747/jokojokoquestion